# Filter an ng-repeat based on parent ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Scratching my head now for 2 hours. Maybe I'm tired or maybe I don't understand what I'm doing. Anyway, I've got an array of blogposts. Which looks like this:

```
[
  {
    'title': 'first post', 
    'tags': [
      { 'name': 'Tag 1', 'slug': 'tag-1' }
    ]
  },
  {
    'title': 'second post', 
    'tags': [
      { 'name': 'Tag 1', 'slug': 'tag-1' },
      { 'name': 'Tag 3', 'slug': 'tag-3' }
    ]
  },
  {
    'title': 'third post', 
    'tags': [
      { 'name': 'Tag 2', 'slug': 'tag-2' }
    ]
  }
]
```

And also an array containing my tags like this.

```
[
  {'title': 'Tag 1', 'slug':'tag-1'},
  {'title': 'Tag 2', 'slug':'tag-2'},
  {'title': 'Tag 3', 'slug':'tag-3'},
  {'title': 'Tag 4', 'slug':'tag-4'}
]
```

And I am doing an regular angular ng-repeat like this to show all my blogpost tags:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="tag in blog.tags">
        <h3>{{ tag.title }}</h3>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now, I would like to add a nested repeater which only shows blogposts from the variable `blog.posts` that contains the current tag.
Something like this:

```
<ul ng-controller="BlogComponent as blog">
  <li ng-repeat="tag in blog.tags">
    <h3>{{ tag.title }}</h3>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="post in blog.posts | filter: tag.slug IN post.tags">
        <span>{{ post.title }}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But I cannot seem to get it working. I think it SHOULD be easy. Because in my mind it is a quite simple task. to filter out unwanted results based on a string and an array.

**Wanted/Exptected output:**

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <h3>Tag 1</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>first post</li>
      <li>second post</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>Tag 2</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>third post</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>Tag 3</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>second post</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You would want to map `post.tags` to an array of the slugs

Comment: Can you please add the actual output which you are expecting out of this?

Comment: Are you still having problems or did one of the answers given help you?

Answer (score 1):

You could make a custom filter instead of using "filter: expression". 
What you can do create a filter that takes the tags and posts as arguments and returns the array with filtered items.

```
myApp.filter('myFilter', function () {
    return function (posts, tag) {
        var newPosts = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) 
            for (var j = 0; j < post.tags.length; j++) 
             if (posts[i].tags[j].slug === tag.slug)
                newPosts.push(posts[i]);

        return newPosts;
    }
});
```

And then

```
  <li ng-repeat="post in blog.posts | myFilter: tag">
    <span>{{ post.title }}</span>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the built-in functionality, you can do it like this:

```
<ul ng-controller="BlogComponent as blog">
  <li ng-repeat="tag in blog.tags">
    <h3>{{ tag.title }}</h3>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="post in blog.posts | filter: {tags: {slug: tag.slug}}">
        <span>{{ post.title }}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

See it working here: https://plnkr.co/edit/pQZse1hUnnzyfneIlpMu?p=preview

Documentation for the filter is here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Or, if you want **Tag 4** to be hidden because it has no matching posts, you could do something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="BlogComponent as blog">
  <div ng-repeat="tag in blog.tags">
    <div ng-repeat="post in blog.posts | filter: {tags: {slug: tag.slug}}">
      <h3 ng-if="$first">{{ tag.title }}</h3>
      <li>{{ post.title }}</li>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```